# What is the correct syntax to signInWithRedirect using firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, mern

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {GoogleOutlined, FacebookOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import "firebase/app";

import { auth } from '../firebase';

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <div id="login-page">
            <div id="login-card">
                <h2> Welcome to myChat Application!</h2>
                <div className="login-button google"
                    onClick = {() => auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())}>
                    <GoogleOutlined /> Sign in with Google
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                <div className="login-button facebook"
                    onClick = {() => auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())}>
                    <FacebookOutlined /> Sign in with Facebook
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

It says

**src\Components\Login.js**

> Line 13:66:  'firebase' is not defined  no-undef        Line 18:66:
> 'firebase' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: try import firebase from 'firebase/app';

Comment: Thanks man. It is solved!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have imported wrongly. It should be

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```